# How to use jQuery validator and jQuery UI Tab together?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, joomla1.5

I'm stuck between jQuery plugins in Joomla. I'm using two plugins together, and now I don't understand how to use it. I'm using the following two plugins.

- jQuery Validator plugin
- jQuery UI tab plugin

I have three forms that I have attatched with UI tabs. All three forms on three tabs are displaying successfully.

Now on the first tab I used jQuery Validator in such a manner that if the form is validated then it is submited (via Ajax) and the second tab opened automatically, this works fine.

But on this second tab I also want to validate that form in a manner that if the second form is validated then the third tab opens automaically otherwise it stops on the second tab and prompt the user to fill in the required form fields.

Now I'm unable to apply form validation on the form which is on the second tab.

I write all JavaScript code in a separate file, `property.js`. For the first form, do I need to add another JavaScript file for the second tab or can we create another instance of `validator` for the second form on that JavaScript file?

Here is my code,

#### /administrator/component/com_property/views/addproperty/tmpl/default.php

```
<?php
    $document->addScript($mask_js);
    $document->addScript($property_js);
    $document->addScript($form_js);
    $document->addScript($widget_js);
    $document->addScript($tab_js);
?>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { display: none; }
</style>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Basic</a></li>
        <li><a href="?option=com_property&view=contact_detail&format=raw">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="?option=com_property&view=xtrafeatures&format=raw">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="?option=com_property&view=upload_images&format=raw">Images</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <fieldset >
            <form name="addPropertyForm" id="addPropertyForm" action="" method="POST" >
                <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
                    <tr>
                      <td ><label for="propTitle"><sup>*</sup>Property Title:</label></td>
                      <td ><input type="text" name="propTitle" id ="propTitle"  size="47"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><label for="prop_type_id"><sup>*</sup>Property Type:</label></td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="prop_type_id" id="prop_type_id" title="Please select Type" validate="required:true" >
                              <option value="">-Select-</option>
                              <option value="0000000001" > Apartment </option>
                              <option value="0000000013" > Commercial </option>
                              <option value="0000000018" > Cottage </option>
                              <option value="0000000019" > Development land </option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><label for="address1"><sup>*</sup>Address line 1:</label></td>
                        <td ><input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" size="47" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td ><label for="price"><sup>*</sup>Price :</td>
                          <td ><input type="text" name="price" id="price" size="47"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="submit" value="Add" name="doAction" class="submit"  />
                        <input type="reset"  value="Clear" name="Clear" class="submit" id="clear"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type='hidden' value='com_property' name='option' />
                <input type='hidden' value='property' name='controller' />
                <input type='hidden' value='storeProperty' name='task' />
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo JUtility::getToken(); ?>" value="1" />
            </form>
        </fieldset>
    </div><!--end of tab 1-->
</div> <!-- end of #tabs -->
```

---

This is the JavaScript file,

#### property.js

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery.metadata.setType("attr", "validate");
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
            cache: false,
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
                    jQuery(anchor.hash).html("<p style='padding:10px'>This Tab is Under Construction</p>");
                }
            }
    }).bind('tabsload', function(event, ui) {
        console.log(ui.index);
    });

    var validator = jQuery("#addPropertyForm").validate({
        debug:true,
        rules: {
            propTitle: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            address1: {
                required: true
            },
            price: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            propTitle: {
                required: "Please write Title",
                minlength: "Property name must consist of at least 2 characters"
            },
            address1: {
                required: "Please write Address"
            },
            price: {
                required: "Please mention Price"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit();
            jQuery("#tabs").tabs( 'select',1);
            jQuery(form).resetForm();
            return false;
           }
    });

    jQuery('#clear').click ( function () {
        validator.resetForm();
    });
});
```

---

#### /administrator/component/com_property/views/contact_detail/tmpl/default.php

```
<fieldset >
    <form name="propertyContactForm" id="propertyContactForm" action="" method="POST" >
        <table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td><label for="contact_office"><sup>*</sup>Contact Office:</label></td>
                <td ><input type="text" name="contact_office" id="contact_office" size="47">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" ><label for="contact_number"><sup>*</sup>Contact Number:</label></td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_number" id="contact_number">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td ><label for="contact_person"><sup>*</sup>Contact Person:</label></td>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <input type="text" name="contact_person" id="contact_person" size="47">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $this->title_text; ?>" name="submitContact" class="submit" id="submitContact" />
                    <input type="button" name="Back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" value="Back" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type='hidden' value='com_property' name='option' />
        <input type='hidden' value='property' name='controller' />
        <input type='hidden' value='StorePropertyContacts' name='task' />
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo JUtility::getToken(); ?>" value="1" />
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to give your each form an unique id and add validator for each form.
In example:

```
jQuery("#addPropertyForm1").validate();
jQuery("#addPropertyForm2").validate();
jQuery("#addPropertyForm3").validate();
```